# How to get excel data into an array to GetBytes from openxml worksheetpart.worksheet c#

Tags: c#, azure, openxml

I have two azure storage container
Container A
Container B
Container A will have an excel file which I will need to download it on the fly & do some modifications for some business logic.
Once modification is done ,the excel file should be uploaded in Container B.
Example:
Excel in Container A have a column named "ABC"  which I will have to replace it with "XYZ"
So a new excel with XYZ content should be saved in Container B.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: I would advice to include some code you have tried else your question will be flagged and removed.

Comment: below is the code where I am trying to convert openxml excel data into bytes

byte[] newdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(worksheetPart.Worksheet.ToString());

Comment: below is the code where I am trying to convert openxml excel data into bytes

byte[] newdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(worksheetPart.Worksheet.ToString());

this newdata byte is passed in another method which is used to upload file in container B.

using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(blobContent))
                    {
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
                    }
upload is working fine, but when I down excel in local & try to open it says the file is corrupt.

Comment: MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save(m);


                        byte[] newdata = m.ToArray();
above issue has been accomplish using memory stream, the file is successfully getting uploaded but when I down load the same file from blob storage & open, it gives error as "Excel cannot open the file, the file format or extension is invalid, verify the file is not corrupted & file extension matches the format of the file"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

1. Upload

```
           string accountName = "jimtestdiag924";
           string accountKey = "uxz4AtF0*********yDSZ7Q+A==";
           var credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
           string url = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName);
           var blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), credential);
           var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("testupload");
           var blobClient =containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.xlsx");
           BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
            
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                await download.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
                {
                    // Access the main Workbook part, which contains all references.
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
                    // get sheet by name
                    Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Sheet1").FirstOrDefault();

                    // get worksheetpart by sheet id
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart;
                    Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "B", 4);

                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue("10");
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

                    // Save the worksheet.
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                    // for recacluation of formula
                    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
                    


                }
               // upload file to another contanier
                ms.Position = 0;
                containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
                await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.xlsx");
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms);
                
               
                download.Content.Close();

            }
```

2. Download

```
           string accountName = "jimtestdiag924";
           string accountKey = "uxz4AtF0*********yDSZ7Q+A==";
           var credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
           string url = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName);
           var blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), credential);
           var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            
           var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.xlsx");
           BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
           using (var file = File.Create(@"D:\test.xlsx")) {

                await download.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
                download.Content.Close();

            }
```

The original excel file

[image]

The new excel file

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim,

Thank you for your reply, after implementation I am getting below stated error.

Ex = {"The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing."}

Comment: @MohammedAmirsayedm Could you tell me where you get the error?

Comment: The error I gets in below line.

using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
                {

Comment: @MohammedAmirsayed please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538982/openxmlsdk-cant-read-manualy-created-xlsx-file-the-specified-package-is-inval

Comment: @MohammedAmirsayed Is it useful for you?

Comment: Actually Jim I am very much new to .net C#, I don't understand if I upload the file from local it is having correct format & able to down load & open file but when I do using above above code while opening uploaded file it says that the file is corrupted.

Comment: The above code works fine local, but when I run this through Function App, it says the "the access is denied on @D:\"
 using (var file = File.Create(@"D:\test.xlsx")) {

                await download.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
                download.Content.Close();

            }

Comment: @MohammedAmirsayed If you want to create file in azure function, you need to store file  in `D:\home`·. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure

Comment: Yes Jim, above full code provided by you as worked for me, as I was new in C#, it took me long for me to implement.
Thank you so much